# function is not showing the success echo on executing?

Tags: php

I am assigning a loop to a function so it's working fine when not enrolled in a function but when it's enrolled in function so it's not showing the echo on success please as :

```
function questions_query() {

    global $mysqli;
    global $form_name;

    $questions = $_POST['questions'];

    for($i=0;$i<count($questions);$i++){

        $i_query = $i+1;

        $query_2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE forms SET question$i_query='$questions[$i]' WHERE form_name='$form_name'") or die(mysqli_connect_error());

    }

}

if (questions_query()) {

    echo "All Questions Are Done!";

}
```

So if you people can please take a look at my code that what is going wrong in there..so I will be thankful to you for that please..!

Comment: The function doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Barmar : But it do run as the query is executed..! I have been checking in database table..!

Answer (score 1):

The function doesn't return anything. There's no `return true;` or `return false;` statement.
If it's not successful it never returns, it calls `die()`, which terminates the whole script. So there's no reason to use `if()` around the call, just do:

```
questions_query();
echo 'All Questions Are Done!';
```

Comment: So how to assign return:true to it and where exactly please?

Comment: as far as it will simply echo if the function still don't run so I want to make it it throw some else on if function didn't get success please..

Answer (score 0):

Want to use return

```
    function questions_query() {

global $mysqli;
global $form_name;

$questions = $_POST['questions'];

for($i=0;$i<count($questions);$i++)
{

$i_query = $i+1;

$query_2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE forms SET question$i_query='$questions[$i]' WHERE form_name='$form_name'") or die(mysqli_connect_error());

}

return true;

}

if (questions_query()) {

echo "All Questions Are Done!";

}

else {

 //something happened
}
```

Comment: Not really but I just want to show the else when the query is not updated as it has to be..!

Comment: if the query is not updating anything means, an error occured. isn't it? or anything else happening

Comment: it's just that query so nothing happens anything without that above mentioned query..!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check MySQL query result, then you need to return error check.

```
function questions_query() {

    global $mysqli;
    global $form_name;

    $questions = $_POST['questions'];

    $has_errors = 0;

    for($i=0;$i<count($questions);$i++)
    {
        $i_query = $i+1;

        $query_2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"...");

        if (mysqli_errno($mysqli) > 0) {
            $has_errors ++;
        }

    }

    return $has_errors;

}

$errors = questions_query();

if ($errors == 0) {
    echo "All Questions Are Done!";
} else {
    echo "Errors in questions: $errors times!";
}
```

Comment: Really it is more advanced code but have just added it updated as `mysqli_errno($mysqli)` per needs..! so it's not echoing the error numbers please..!